# prevent refresh after subscribe in anglar

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

### the customer loud image and i send the image to my Server according to copy her to my folder and when back the response the page refresh i  want to prevent this situation-

angular

html

```
            <button mat-button class="load" (click)="onClick()">
              <mat-label>התאמה על פי תמונה</mat-label>
                       <mat-icon>file_upload</mat-icon>
                            </button>

                            <input type="file" #fileUpload id="fileUpload" 
            name="fileUpload" multiple="multiple" accept="image/*"
                            style="display:none;" 
              (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)" [(ngModel)]="image" 
                   />
                    
                    <img *ngIf="availbule" [src]="imgURL" style="width: 
                250px;height: 
              150px;" />
```

componnent.ts

send image from the File Explorer to copy her to my folder

```
         uploadFile(file) { 
         var arr = this.fileToUpLoud.name.split('/');
         let ima = arr[arr.length - 1];
         var end=ima.split('.');
         const formData = new FormData();
         this.namera=Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 1000 + 1)) + 1000;
         this.propertySearch.img=(this.namera).toString()+
         formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en')+'.'+(end[end.length-1]).toString();
         formData.append('file', file.data,this.propertySearch.img);
         file.inProgress = true;
         this._modelService.uploadimageSearch(formData)
         .subscribe(data => {
          if(data==true){
          alert("true")}
          else{
          alert("false");
          }
    
          }); 
       }
```

---

service

```
    public uploadimageSearch(file: FormData): Observable<boolean> { 
          return this.httpClient.post<boolean>("/api/Model/addNewcustomerImage", file);
     }
```

---

c# net core

this function get image and copy her to some location

```
    public async Task<bool> addNewcustomerImage(IFormFile file)
    {
        try
        {


            string end = file.FileName;

            string imgPath = @"C:/Users/AVITAL/Desktop/my-first-project/src/assets/image/";

            string finalPath = imgPath + end;

            using (var stream = new FileStream(finalPath, FileMode.Create))
            {7 
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
                stream.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)

        { 
            return false;
        }
    
        return true;

    }
```

Comment: It is not clear what problem you are having.

Comment: is this a form?

Comment: yes the client need loud image and i want to copy her to my folder but when the server return response the page loud

Comment: Could you show the form code please

Comment: I don't see a form, just a button, so is this a `form` or just a button?

Answer (score 0):

**in angular**

```
this._modelService.uploadimageSearch(formData)
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data == true) {
      window.location.reload(false); 
    } 
  }, (error: Error) => {
   console.log(error);
});
```